Some pages of the site return 500, SEO from Google Search Console does not index
I have build this site, and want to index each project on this page.
https://www.silkysound.no/projects
But Google Search Console returns 500 status on these pages.
For example this project: https://www.silkysound.no/projects/om-sorg
The site has SSR on Nextjs 14. Each project is a React component "use client", but it gets the content for each project which generated on the server SSR.
The site is deployed on Vercel.
Any idea how to solve the 500 status? Thx :)

